# Unsure how to Parse arguments and utilise excevp function

Tags: c, execvp

I am trying to write a Program called *Generate* that basically creates a child process to execute a particular process and print some statistics with regard to the execution of the process

Suppose my input on the terminal is `./Generate ./a 123 234` ,

- I know I can collect the input with `main(int args, char **argv)`.
- I know `argv[0]` = ./Generate , `argv[1]`, =./a , `argv[2]` = 123 , `argc[3]`= 1234.
- I create a child process and want it to use function `execvp()`, to execute `./a 123 234.`

How would I go about doing the same Example:

```
if (pid == 0){
    execvp(a[0],a); // I want 'a' here to contain my input
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all parameters pass to your program are the command line of the program to invoke, you can do the following:

```
execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
```

Since `argv` is an array of pointers, `&argv[1]` gives you a pointer to the second element in that array, so the remaining elements will follow.